# Intro to mysql I cant seem to create the data base given the instructions

Tags: mysql

Hello I am currently trying to create a database with my last name then showing the database then updating the data base back to last name here and then using the data base and creating a pair of tables. I am learning through codio and I am having trouble creating the data base.[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvxC5.png)
Create a new database and update the name to your last name, then connect to it.

```
Create database {last_name};
```

For example, if your database is going to be named Jetson, then substitute `Jetson` for `last_name`

```
use {last_name};
```

Capture a screenshot or clipping of the results of this action, and place it in a Word document for submission.
Create a table called tb2 and list out the tables in your database with one field by typing the following commands after the prompt mysql>

```
create table tb2 (user_id VARCHAR( 50 ));

describe tb2;
```

Capture a screenshot or clipping of the results of this action, and place it in a Word document for submission.
Now, add a second field by entering the following commands after

```
alter table tb2 add newfield VARCHAR(25);


describe tb2;
```

I can't seem to create the database what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wow - you might consider legibility

Answer (score 0):

You're using enclosing parentheses while creating table.

Use `CREATE DATABASE chaput` without `(` and `)`

Comment: Hey thanks for the help I thought the () were supposed to be there ha its been a rocky start. but I'm starting to get it thank you again.